# Signing in an account to use google play leaderboard

Tags: google-play-services, google-signin

The following sign in code causes my game to flicker then crash after printing "bad stuff". What am I doing wrong? I tried to implement the code shown [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin). I attempt a silent sign in, then if that does not work I attempt an interactive sign in. I am testing an a physical Nexus 5 with the latest version of Android 8.1.0.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView mGLView;
private GoogleSignInAccount account;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this, this);
    setContentView(mGLView);
    hideStatusBar();
    getAccount();
}
public void hideStatusBar() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    //ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.hide();
}
private void getAccount() {
    account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (account == null) {
        signInSilently();
    }
}
public void submitScore(int score) {
    if (account == null) {
        getAccount();
    } else {
        Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, account)
                .submitScore("leaderboardID", score);
    }
}
private static final int leaderboardRequestCode = 9004;
private static final int signInRequestCode = 101;
public void showLeaderboard() {
    if (account == null) {
        getAccount();
    } else {
        Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, account)
                .getLeaderboardIntent("leaderboardID")
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, leaderboardRequestCode);
                    }
                });
    }
}

//interactive sign in
private void startSignInIntent() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, signInRequestCode);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == signInRequestCode) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            account = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "bad stuff";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}

//silent sign in
private void signInSilently() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        account = task.getResult();
                    } else {
                        startSignInIntent();
                    }
                }
            });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    signInSilently();
}
}
```

Comment: Is this the user's first attempt to sign-in? Silent sign-in is for already-logged in users.

Comment: Yes but I't doesn't work even if I only try interactive sign in, and my silent signin function falls back to interactive sign in anyway.

Comment: I was able to get the flickering to stop by removing onResume invocation but the sign in still fails with no error message.

Comment: I have entered my debug shaw1 in the google api console for the app. I added another link in the "linked apps" in google play games console, so there are now two rows, one of which is the client id associated with my debug shaw1. Still prints "bad stuff" when I run from Android Studio. Also tried Internal release and Alpha release in play console. Sign in still prints "bad stuff". I can't even get an error message.